# Facebook like button pops up behind some elements

Tags: facebook, popup, facebook-like, overflow, z-index

On my website the comment box that pops up when I press the Like button is placed behind some elements of the page and I really don't figure out how to fix it.

For 2 days I'm struggling with z-index property but no result and now I've found a solution by changing the overflow property of the parent div from hidden to visible/auto and it works! BUT I can't use this fix because that div has overflow set to hidden because I'm using the slimScroll plugin to customize the scrollbar...

[This](http://www.decorative.ro/en/figurative-art) is the website, just click on any image and press the Like button to see what happens.

The right and left side of the popup are integrated in a table... I was thinking, if i remove the table and use just divs instead, the fix would be easier?

Thanks!

Comment: where do you want to re position the textbox?

Comment: i don't want to reposition the comment box, i just want to be fully visible. If you press the like button you'll see that the commentbox that pops up is half behind the big picture from left

Comment: so you want it to appear in front of the art?

Comment: yeah, that's what I intent to do.